# Create thumbnails of sections of a torrent stream

Tags: node.js, file-io, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a little application in nodejs using the `torrent-stream` library to create thumbnails of a video without actually having to download the entire file. I was thinking of downloading only 10 parts, out of which I would extract an image, but then the encoding comes into play: without an `I-frame` I cannot extract an image out of the stream, and there is no way of me knowing where the I-frame is.

So any ideas on how to do this? Basically I was hoping to create 10 tiny files which I could then open in ffmpeg in order to save a thumbnail (this would give me 10 thumbnails which is want I want). I'm just not sure how to handle the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at peerflix: 
https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix
Specifically look at how it does CORS range requests.
Then, integrate it with a codec like:

```
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
```

10 thumbnails are 10 range requests and the swarm has to spin up for each one, so it will not be fast. Kind of thing you would want to run in the background and store in a cache.

You might be able to speed it up by running multiple torrent-streams at the same time.